# How can modify this indicator so that it only shows data for a certain amounts of periods?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator

This indicator shows previous periods (day and week) high, low and open.

I would like to add options so I can choose how many periods it should go back.

For example, only the last day or week, or 2 days or weeks.

Any help would be great for me.

Thank you!

```
study(title="Previous Day High and Low + OPENS", shorttitle="HLO", overlay=true)

D_High = security(tickerid, 'D', high[1]) 
D_Low = security(tickerid, 'D', low[1]) 
D_Close =  security(tickerid, 'D', close[1]) 
D_Open =  security(tickerid, 'D', open[1]) 
W_High =  security(tickerid, 'W', high[1]) 
W_Low =  security(tickerid, 'W', low[1])


plot(isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 
plot(isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 

plot(isintraday ? W_High : na, title="Weekly High",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 
plot(isintraday ? W_Low : na, title="Weekly Low",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 

openPriceD = security(tickerid, 'D', open)

openPriceW = security(tickerid, 'W', open)

openPriceM = security(tickerid, 'M', open)

plot(openPriceD ? openPriceD : na, title="Daily Open", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=purple)

plot(openPriceW ? openPriceW : na, title="Weekly Open", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=green)

plot(openPriceM ? openPriceM : na, title="Monthly Open", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=red)
```